# PG::ConnectionBad: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "alphauser"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, authentication

I'm working on an application in Rails for my college. The application was started by the students from previous year and now it's me and my colleagues turn to continue work on it. I took the application from github, I run bundle install, but when to run `rake db:migrate` I got this `PG::ConnectionBad: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "alphauser"`.
In  database.yml I have these

```
 development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: alpha_database
  host: localhost
  pool: 5
  username: alphauser
  password: alphapassword
```

I don't know what to do in this case.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You have to create corresponding user and database manually like this:

in shell:
`psql`

then:

```
  create user alphauser with password 'alphapassword';
  create database alpha_database owner alphauser;
  alter user alphauser superuser createrole createdb replication;
  \q
```

don't forget semicolons.

Comment: I couldn't even create a new user. Something about not having the permissions to do so. So I first did `$ sudo su - postgres`, entered my password (I'm on Ubuntu) before calling `psql` and then I continued with your answers.

Comment: How can you log into `psql` when enter `psql` on the terminal also unsuccessful?

Answer (score 5):

Try to use:

> sudo -u postgres createuser --interactive --pwprompt

to add the role and the password

Answer (score 3):

So the problem is with your rails application using the `database.yml` file to try and connect to your local database and failing to find the user `alphauser` (since I assume you're using different computers/environments as the previous students).

Databases have users similar to applications, the postgres documentation is pretty dense on this, but I would guess if you can create a user `alphauser`, and make it's password `alphapassword` then you will have a new clean database for your app that you can run `rake db:migrate` on.

Postgres docs: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/app-createuser.html

Try running this command from the command line `createuser -P -s -e alphauser`

This will prompt for a password, which is `alphauserpassword`

Answer (score 1):

```
 create user alphauser with password 'alphapassword';
```

Then

```
rake db:setup
```