# rake db:create password authentication fails for user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication

While running the command `rake db:create`, the system throws `postgresql authentication fails`

```
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"postgresql", "encoding"=>"unicode", "pool"=>5, "username"=>"postgres", "password"=>"password", "timeout"=>5000, "host"=>"localhost", "database"=>"rails-sample-guestbook-master_development"}
rake aborted!
```

database.yml file

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: 5
  username: supranimbus
  password: 123456789
  timeout: 5000
  host: localhost
development:
  <<: *default
  database: rails-sample-guestbook-master_development

test:
  <<: *default
  database: rails-sample-guestbook-master_test

production:
  <<: *default
  database: rails-sample-guestbook-master_production
```

Comment: you could check your password settings in your config file (`database.yml`), is your password really `password` only word?

Comment: Please share your `database.yml`

Comment: Find out if you configured your postgres database properly.

Comment: How is your database configured? How is your rails application configured? You haven't shared *either* of these things with us, so it's impossible to answer the question... But *almost certainly*, the issue is that those two configurations do not match.

Comment: default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: 5
  username: supranimbus
  password: 123456789
  timeout: 5000
  host: localhost
development:
  <<: *default
  database: rails-sample-guestbook-master_development

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  <<: *default
  database: rails-sample-guestbook-master_test

production:
  <<: *default
  database: rails-sample-guestbook-master_production

Comment: Can you check if you have a user in postgres with username and password as mentioned in question?

Comment: yeah, I have mentioned postgres username and password

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PG::ConnectionBad: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "alphauser"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28793606/pgconnectionbad-fatal-password-authentication-failed-for-user-alphauser)

Answer (score 1):

I guess the problem is setup password on `postgresql` if you don't remember the default password then go to **pgAdmin** click to open dashboard and then the left sidebar see the below image

[image]

Click the **Properties...** then will open a modal like see the below image

[image]

and click the **Definition** tab and see the **Password** field and set the new password, remember this password for `postgres` username.

That's is for password setup!

Now update your `database.yml` file like below

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  username: postgres
  password: 123456 #=> which you set for postgres
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>

development:
  <<: *default
  database: project_development
```

Hope to help